# Juptyer says it installed a kernel but it's still not available

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a virtualenv in `~/.virtualenvs` that I want to make available to Juptyer. I ask Juptyer to install it, and Jupyter says that it did, but it still doesn't appear in the `kernelspec list` (or as an option under "change kernel" in Juptyer. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ jupyter kernelspec install --user  --replace ~/.virtualenvs/my-env
[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec my-env in /Users/me/Library/Jupyter/kernels/my-env
$ jupyter kernelspec list                                                                                                                                                 Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/me/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the following a go

`ipython kernel install --user --name=my-env`

That's how I've been adding kernels to Jupyter and I've had no problems so far.  However, you need to ensure that you have run `pip install ipykernel` INSIDE YOUR VENV, before you can do this.